# Can zsh complete command flags?

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, flags, zshrc

Is there some way to get zsh to complete long flag names on the command line?

```
$ command --reall<tab> 
$ command --really-long-flag-name
```

Seems like a zshy thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is yes, or course it can.

To turn on zsh’s completion system, you need to do the following – probably in a startup file like your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U compinit && compinit
```

On most modern Unix-like systems, once you do that you ought to find that many commands already have their flags and parameters completed, because zsh ships with a library of completion functions for common Unix commands and utilities.  This library ought to be installed in a location like `/usr/local/share/zsh/function` (or similar, depending on your system) and consists of a bunch of scripts with filenames starting in a `_` character, each of which defines the completion for a specific command.

If a command or utility you’re interested in is not yet completed correctly by zsh, you have several options:

- Look into the [zsh-completions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions) package.  (It may well be installable by your operating system or distribution’s package manager.)
- Read the documentation for the tool you wish to have completion.  Many Unix utilities ship with completion scripts for bash and/or zsh, or with some way of generating completion scripts.
- If all else fails, read the [documentation on zsh’s completion system](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) (or find a good book or online tutorial) and write it yourself.  This can — obviously — be non-trivial!

Reading that zsh documentation might also show you how to do other things that you may not even know yet that you want, like turning on menu-based completion.

Comment: a small addition which is probably worth quoting directly from zsh-completions is `compdef _gnu_generic <COMMANDNAME>` which parses the `--help` output of the command to assemble the completion.

Comment: Thanks @wjv -- I believe I had a problem with `compinit` in my `.zshrc`. It works as expected now.

Comment: @Sasgorilla Good, glad to hear it.